# How to parse data reader?

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my UWP app, I am responding to write BLE write requests with the following code:

```
private async void WriteCharacteristic_WriteRequested(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, GattWriteRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    string runStr = string.Empty;
    var deferral = args.GetDeferral();

    var request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
    var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(request.Value);

    while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
    {
        var iRead = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        runStr = runStr + iRead;

        // I tried this but it throws an exception
        //uint inBufferCnt = await reader.LoadAsync(20);
    }

    if (request.Option == GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse)
    {
        request.Respond();
    }

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

I am following the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server#respond-to-read-and-write-requests)

It reads the write request, but if the text being sent/written is too long, it gets cut off. I think I'm supposed to continue reading the data reader, but it throws an exception when I try calling `await reader.LoadAsync(20)`:

> The operation identifier is not valid.

If I don't call this function, my `runStr` variable will contain the text, but truncated when too long.

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader.loadasync#remarks) The read operation can get more or fewer bytes depending on how the `InputStreamOptions` property is set. Please try set InputStreamOptions property before load data.